# How to convert String to String array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

I want to know how I can convert one string or a String Object in a `String array` using kotlin.

I made some research and found this JAVA code which seems to do what I need.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
String word="abc";
        String[] array = new String[word.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            array[i] = String.valueOf(word.charAt(i));
        }

        for(String a:array){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
}
```

I expect to have something like this or better than it in Kotlin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's complicated. Java sample is incorrect, thus, direct translations to Kotlin are incorrect, too. The problem is that `char` is not a character or code point but a UTF-16 word which can represent a half of a code point. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878804/how-to-count-grapheme-clusters-or-perceived-emoji-characters-in-java, and use builtin IntelliJ J2K converter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this:

```
val str = "abcd"
val array: Array<String> = str.toCharArray().map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: A bit simpler:

`str.map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray()`

Comment: You can also simply allocate the result to a string list like this:`val listStr: List<String> = str.map { it.toString() }`

Answer (score 8):

Try This:

```
val str = "Hello"
val arr = str.split("")

fun main() {
    println(arr) // [, H, e, l, l, o]
}
```

Comment: String.split("") returns a List<String>, but the question is about Array<String>.

Comment: You can append `.toTypedArray()` to convert list to array

Answer (score 5):

You can fill an array as you initialize it using a lambda that takes the index as an argument.

```
fun main() {
    val word = "abcd"
    val array = Array(word.length) {word[it].toString()}
    array.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java.text.BreakIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) both from Java and Kotlin-JVM to iterate through 'grapheme clusters', i. e. user-visible 'characters'.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val string = "Hello"
    val array = Array(string.length) { string[it].toString() }
}
```