# Separating vowels and consonants in indic/abugida scripts using python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, indic

I am trying to build a programme that will help me convert unicode abugida script into a list of vowels and consonants. I have achieved separation of phonetic sounds using the following script taken from [Playing around with Devanagari characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805311/playing-around-with-devanagari-characters)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodedata, sys

def splitclusters(s):
    """Generate the grapheme clusters for the string s. (Not the full
    Unicode text segmentation algorithm, but probably good enough for
    Devanagari.)

    """
    virama = u'\N{DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA}'
    cluster = u''
    last = None
    for c in s:
        cat = unicodedata.category(c)[0]
        if cat == 'M' or cat == 'L' and last == virama:
            cluster += c
        else:
            if cluster:
                yield cluster
            cluster = c
        last = c
    if cluster:
        yield cluster

name_in_indic = raw_input('Enter your name in devanagari: ').decode('utf8')

print (','.join(list(splitclusters(name_in_indic))))
```

However, my intention is to go further and separate all the vowels and consonants .

```
E.g हिंदी = ह+इ+न+द+ई
```

which is the same as hindi becoming h+i+n+d+i only in indic scripts each phoneme is treating as a character

How do i go about this?

Comment: What about parsing the string by each character and matching it to the unicode of the vowel graphemes?

Comment: SO basically the input should consist of the vowels and consonants separated?

Comment: I think I misread the original question, sorry.